# imported enums vs local enums in typescript

Tags: typescript

Why are imported enums different from local enums?

```js
import { Directions as ImportedDirections} from './importedEnums.ts'
enum Directions {
  Up = "UP",
  Down = "DOWN",
  Left = "LEFT",
  Right = "RIGHT",
}
enum GoUp {
  Up = Directions.Up,
}
enum GoUpUsingImportedDirections {
  Up = ImportedDirections.Up,
}

console.log('GoUp', GoUp)
console.log('GoUpUsingImportedDirections', GoUpUsingImportedDirections)
```

./importedEnums.ts

```
export enum Directions {
  Up = "UP",
  Down = "DOWN",
  Left = "LEFT",
  Right = "RIGHT",
}
```

the compiled result is

```js
var s = ((e) => (
    (e.Up = "UP"), (e.Down = "DOWN"), (e.Left = "LEFT"), (e.Right = "RIGHT"), e
  ))(s || {}),
  c = ((e) => (
    (e.Up = "UP"), (e.Down = "DOWN"), (e.Left = "LEFT"), (e.Right = "RIGHT"), e
  ))(c || {}),
  i = ((e) => ((e.Up = "UP"), e))(i || {}),
  u = ((e) => ((e[(e.Up = s.Up)] = "Up"), e))(u || {});

console.log("GoUp", i);
console.log("GoUpUsingImportedDirections", u);
```

why imported enums get https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings

enum `GoUpUsingImportedDirections` not reversed mapped